# Apache Velocity $ vs $!{}

Tags: apache, velocity

For apache velocity, is there a difference between accessing variables with $ vs. $!{}. If so, what is it?

Answer (score 25):

There's two differences, the second is [**formal**](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/user-guide.html#formalreferencenotation) and [**quiet**](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation).

Formal reference notations include the braces around the variable. The quiet notation includes the `!` and means to output nothing if the reference does not exist. When combining them, you create a formal and quiet notation.